# Help Interpret Advanced Array Work in Lightning JS

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, javascript-controller, array

I didn't write but rather I'm reviewing the following Lightning JS function:

```
InitializeComponent : function (component) {

        var recId = component.get("v.recordId");

        var action = component.get("c.Init");
        action.setParams({ "recordId" : recId });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var resp = response.getReturnValue();
            if (component.isValid()) {

                if ($A.util.isEmpty(resp.RowData)) {
                    this.setErrorState(component, "No row data was returned for the Time Report");
                    return;
                }

                // move the root level node for the treeGrid
                resp.RowData[0]["_children"] = resp.RowData[0]["us_children"];
                delete resp.RowData[0]["us_children"];  

                // grab the root children and update the _children attribute for treeGrid requirements
                for (let x of resp.RowData[0]["_children"]) {
                    x["_children"] = x["us_children"];
                    delete x["us_children"];
                }
                component.set("v.initResponse",resp);
                this.HideSpinner(component);                
            }
        },"SUCCESS");

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            this.setErrorState(component, response.getError()[0].message);
        },"ERROR");

        $A.enqueueAction(action);   

    }
```

It populates a **lightning:treeGrid** [component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:treeGrid/documentation).

I'm confused about what's happening in this part:

```
// move the root level node for the treeGrid
resp.RowData[0]["_children"] = resp.RowData[0]["us_children"];
delete resp.RowData[0]["us_children"];  

// grab the root children and update the _children attribute for treeGrid requirements
for (let x of resp.RowData[0]["_children"]) {
    x["_children"] = x["us_children"];
    delete x["us_children"];
}
```

again, `resp = response.getReturnValue()`.  Drilling down into the value returned from the server as far as possible, `resp.RowData[0]` looks like this when debugging the server side action:

```
RowData:[BillableHours=37.50, 
         Name=Total, 
         NonBillableHours=0.5, 
         RowId=TOTALS, 
         TotalHours=null, 
         us_children=(RowData:[BillableHours=3.25, 
                               Name=John Doe, 
                               NonBillableHours=0, 
                               RowId=John Doe, 
                               TotalHours=null, 
                               us_children=(RowData:[BillableHours=3.25, 
                                                     Name=Project Management, 
                                                     NonBillableHours=0, 
                                                     RowId=John DoeProject Management, 
                                                     TotalHours=null, 
                                                     us_children=()])], 
                        RowData:[BillableHours=33.25, 
                                 Name=John Doe2, 
                                 NonBillableHours=0, 
                                 RowId=John Doe2, 
                                 TotalHours=null, 
                                 us_children=(RowData:[BillableHours=32.75, 
                                                       Name=Consulting Services, 
                                                       NonBillableHours=0, 
                                                       RowId=John Doe2Consulting Services, 
                                                       TotalHours=null, 
                                                       us_children=()], 
                                              RowData:[BillableHours=0.5, 
                                                       Name=Project Management, 
                                                       NonBillableHours=0, 
                                                       RowId=John Doe2Project Management, 
                                                       TotalHours=null, 
                                                       us_children=()])], 
                        RowData:[BillableHours=1.0, 
                                 Name=John Doe3, 
                                 NonBillableHours=0.5, 
                                 RowId=John Doe3, 
                                 TotalHours=null, 
                                 us_children=(RowData:[BillableHours=1.0, 
                                                       Name=Consulting Services, 
                                                       NonBillableHours=0, 
                                                       RowId=John Doe3Consulting Services, 
                                                       TotalHours=null, 
                                                       us_children=()], 
                                              RowData:[BillableHours=0, 
                                                       Name=Project Management, 
                                                       NonBillableHours=0.5, 
                                                       RowId=John Doe3Project Management, 
                                                       TotalHours=null, 
                                                       us_children=()])])]
```

Debugging the client side, `resp.RowData[0]["_children"]` starts out `undefined` and `resp.RowData[0]["us_children"]` is:

[image]

So:

Does `resp.RowData[0]["_children"] = resp.RowData[0]["us_children"];` actually, on the spot, create a "_children" item at the 0 index *and* simultaneously sets it equal to `resp.RowData[0]["us_children"]`?

At any rate, what's going on in the loop?

And don't `resp.RowData[0]["_children"]` and `resp.RowData[0]["us_children"]` imply named indices - "_children" and "us_children" respectively?  If so, I thought they weren't allowed in JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This inefficient code is working around an Apex limitation that variable names may not start with an underscore ("_"), yet `lightning:treeGrid` requires `_children` in order to show the child elements. Their solution was to have a variable named `us_children`, that they then recursively strip off the `us` in front and delete the original keys. In JavaScript, practically anything can be a key, so long as it is contained in an `Object`, usually denoted as `{}`. This is contrast to an `Array`, usually denoted as `[]`, which is meant to hold only numeric indexes, as you'd expect.

This code expects the data to be no more than 2 layers deep; anything more than that won't properly translated, and will not appear as increasing grid levels. In addition, it also automatically assumes one top-level element in the list. While this is all fine, it's incredibly fragile and certainly not as clean as it could be. With a simple recursive function, this could all be fixed up easily:

```
resp.RowData.forEach(function recurse(item) {
    if(item.us_children) {
        item.us_children.forEach(recurse);
        item._children = item.us_children;
        delete item.us_children;
    }
});
```

While this is about the same lines of code, it (hopefully) makes it clear that we're recursively moving `us_children` to `_children`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take.

For your question:

> Does `resp.RowData[0]["_children"] = resp.RowData[0]["us_children"];` actually, on the spot, create a "_children" item at the 0 index and simultaneously sets it equal to `resp.RowData[0]["us_children"]?`

**Yes**. In [lightning:treeGrid](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:treeGrid/documentation), if you want to display **nested** components those are in your response data, you will need to use the **_children** keyword. It's not an index but a key at a particular index, that's used by the platform to traverse through the nested contents.

Here's what is says in the documentation:

> Nested items must be defined using the ***_children*** key.

---

> And don't resp.RowData[0]["_children"] and resp.RowData[0]["us_children"] imply named indices - "_children" and "us_children" respectively? If so, I thought they weren't allowed in JS?

I am not completely aware of JS named indices, but in this case, it does not seem to be an index but the **key** defined with the name *_children* at the element at that particular index.

---

> At any rate, what's going on in the loop?

As far as I can understand, within the loop, its just traversing through all the nested children at 0-th index, and then updating the node with the contents from *us_children* and deleting the *us_children* node details, so that all nested child elements are traversed by the component just by using *_children* keyword.